# Prometheus python exporter for json values

Tags: python, python-3.x, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I have a scenario where I am fetching and formatting json response then I want to use the Prometheus-python client to convert the [json data](https://jsfiddle.net/2em8bx1a/) which is obtained from `response` into Prometheus relevant metrics.

Here is what I have tried :

```
import time
from prometheus_client.core import GaugeMetricFamily, REGISTRY, CounterMetricFamily
from prometheus_client import start_http_server
import requests
import json

class CustomCollector(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def collect(self):
        response = requests.get('https://api.test.com/v1/data', auth= 
        ('abc@gg.com', 'xxrty'))
        d1=(response.json())
        for key in d1:
           g = GaugeMetricFamily("devicevalue", 'Help text', labels=['datalnddev'])
           g.add_metric([key['appname'], key['value'])
           yield g

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_http_server(8003)
    REGISTRY.register(CustomCollector())
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
```

But this does not help to solve the issue, I am not sure how to proceed here any help would be great.
expected [exporter metrics](https://jsfiddle.net/pLd04ryz/) output in prometheus.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of your code is fine, however there are some minor mistakes. 
 - in your json data, there is one element with key `appnamet` (with extra `t` at the end).
 - when you are iterating through your data, you forgot to get list by key "app_metric"
 - you should convert label values to string, like on example below (`[str(key['appname'])]`)

```py
import time
from prometheus_client.core import GaugeMetricFamily, REGISTRY, CounterMetricFamily
from prometheus_client import start_http_server
import requests
import json

class CustomCollector(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def collect(self):
        # response = requests.get('https://api.test.com/v1/data', auth= ('abc@gg.com', 'xxrty'))
        d1 = {
            "app_metric": [
                {
                "appname": 18,
                "value": "0"
                },
                {
                "appname": 12,
                "value": "0"
                },
                {
                "appname": 123,
                "value": "0"
                },
                {
                "appname": 134,
                "value": "0"
                }
            ]
        }
        list_of_metrics = d1["app_metric"]
        for key in list_of_metrics:
           g = GaugeMetricFamily("devicevalue", 'Help text', labels=['datalnddev'])
           g.add_metric([str(key['appname'])], key['value'])
           yield g

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_http_server(8003)
    REGISTRY.register(CustomCollector())
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
```

With this example, I'm getting your desired result:

```
# HELP devicevalue Help text
# TYPE devicevalue gauge
devicevalue{datalnddev="18"} 0.0
# HELP devicevalue Help text
# TYPE devicevalue gauge
devicevalue{datalnddev="12"} 0.0
# HELP devicevalue Help text
# TYPE devicevalue gauge
devicevalue{datalnddev="123"} 0.0
# HELP devicevalue Help text
# TYPE devicevalue gauge
devicevalue{datalnddev="134"} 0.0
```

Comment: but these results me the values two times
`
`# HELP devicevalue Help text
# TYPE devicevalue gauge
devicevalue{datalnddev="18"} 0.0
# HELP devicevalue Help text
# TYPE devicevalue gauge
devicevalue{datalnddev="18"} 0.0
# HELP devicevalue Help text
# TYPE devicevalue gauge
# HELP devicevalue Help text
# TYPE devicevalue gauge
devicevalue{datalnddev="12"} 0.0
# HELP devicevalue Help text
# TYPE devicevalue gauge
devicevalue{datalnddev="12"} 0.0
# HELP devicevalue Help text
# TYPE devicevalue gauge`

Comment: Not sure, what you mean by that, Maybe your API returns duplicated values?
With JSON example you provided I get one line for each "appname". Please run the code, I provider and see if it gives you desired result on `localhost:8003`. If it does, look for problems on your API response

Comment: @Paulius Is there any particular reason to use g = GaugeMetricFamily("devicevalue", 'Help text', labels=['datalnddev']) inside collect method and inside loop.
Why we cannot use it before loop or inside __init__(self)? Can you please help with this? I am a little bit confused.

Comment: @user_123, I posted this answer long time ago,  it looks like you are right `GaugeMetricFamily` can be initiated once, outside the loop. I've probably just copied this code snippet from the question and didn't bother to refactor it, I only addressed the issue mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Paulius So is it mandatory to reload the page to get the updated result or it will auto-reload the updated data?

Comment: @user_123, when you configure targets on Prometheus side, you can specify `scrape_interval` (default 1min). Prometheus will scrape your endpoints and store the metrics in its database on frequency defined by `scrape_interval`. Thats how Prometheus works. If you are just calling metrics endpoint directly, without Prometheus, then yes - you have to refresh the page to see newest metric values.

Comment: @Paulius I observed when I used 500 data then it takes time. Is Prometheus reloading slow at the first time? I used your suggested options I just multiply the list of dict by 500.